# How to create dataframe from numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following `numpy` array:

```
numpy_x.shape

(9982, 26)
```

`numpy_x` have 9982 records/observations and 26 columns index. Is this right really?

```
numpy_x[:]
array([[0.00000000e+00, 9.60000000e-01, 1.00000000e+00, ...,
        1.20000000e+00, 6.90000000e-01, 1.17000000e+00],
       [1.00000000e+00, 9.60000000e-01, 1.00000000e+00, ...,
        1.20000000e+00, 7.00000000e-01, 1.17000000e+00],
       [2.00000000e+00, 9.60000000e-01, 1.00000000e+00, ...,
        1.20000000e+00, 7.00000000e-01, 1.17000000e+00],
       ...,
       [9.97900000e+03, 6.10920994e-01, 7.58135980e-01, ...,
        1.08704204e+00, 7.88187535e-01, 1.23021669e+00],
       [9.98000000e+03, 6.10920994e-01, 7.58135980e-01, ...,
        1.08704204e+00, 7.88187535e-01, 1.23021669e+00],
       [9.98100000e+03, 6.10920994e-01, 7.58135980e-01, ...,
        1.08704204e+00, 7.88187535e-01, 1.23021669e+00]])
```

I want generate a dataframe with numpy_x data, index and columns (index and columns are the same really?), then I proceed to perform the following:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data=numpy_x[:], # I want pass the entire numpy array content
            index=numpy_x[1:26],
            columns=numpy_x[9982:26])
```

But I get the following error:

```
/.conda/envs/x/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   4606         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
   4607     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(
-> 4608         passed, implied))
   4609 
   4610 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (26, 9982), indices imply (0, 25)
```

How to can I understand what parameters pass on `index` and `columns` attributes?

Comment: `columns` are the columns that you require for your table. `indices` are kind of group by value by which the table will be indexed with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
numpy_x=np.random.random((100,10))
df=pd.DataFrame(numpy_x)
```

**Output**

```
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0  0.204839  0.837503  0.696896  0.235414  0.594766  0.521302  0.841167
1  0.041490  0.679537  0.657314  0.656672  0.524983  0.936918  0.482802
2  0.318928  0.423196  0.218037  0.515017  0.107851  0.564404  0.218297
3  0.644913  0.433771  0.297033  0.011239  0.346021  0.353749  0.587631
4  0.127949  0.517230  0.969399  0.743442  0.268566  0.415327  0.567572

          7         8         9
0  0.882685  0.211414  0.659820
1  0.752496  0.047198  0.775250
2  0.521580  0.655942  0.178753
3  0.123761  0.483601  0.157191
4  0.849218  0.098588  0.754402
```

**I want generate a dataframe with numpy_x data, index and columns (index and columns are the same really?)**

Yes and no. [`Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) is simply the axis labelling information in `pandas`. Depending upon the axis, Index can either mean row indexing or column indexing.

The axis labeling information in pandas objects serves many purposes:

- Identifies data (i.e. provides metadata) using known indicators,
  important for analysis, visualization, and interactive console
  display
- Enables automatic and explicit data alignment
- Allows intuitive getting and setting of subsets of the data set

It can also be a simple single integer index or it can also be [`Multi-Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

**`Index` and `Columns` Parameter**

The `columns` parameter is simply the column labels that you want to provide to your dataset, in this case you want to pass *26* names for the 26 columns in your `numpy` array. This will default to `np.arange(n)` if no column labels are provided

The `index` parameter is simply the Index to use for the resulting frame. Will default to `np.arange(n)` if no indexing information part of input data and no index provided (which is what is the case in my example)

Comment: This mean, that the pd function receive a numpy array and by default take your content, index and columns and is in the capacity or transform it on dataframe ...

Comment: Yes. Actually most of the `pd` implementations are in `numpy`. So by default it supports a lot of `numpy` operations off the shelf including consuming `numpy` arrays